# Jquery: children of this

Tags: jquery

If I have a container with an image in it...

```
<div id="container">
<img src="myimage.jpg">
</div>
```

How do I reference it using **this**?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#container").click(function(){
    $(this:image).fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove();});
 });
```

Comment: Does anyone else think that "jQuery: Children of This" would be an excellent title for a movie blockbuster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` isn't a jQuery object, you have to either turn it into a jQuery object, then search within it using `find` (or `children`, if you only want direct children).  Or, alternatively, supply it as the context (starting point) for a selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#container").click(function(){
      $(this).find('img').fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove();});
   });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#container").click(function(){
      $('img',this).fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove();});
   });
});
```

Note that this will remove only the image after it has been faded out. If you want to remove the entire DIV you'll need to store a reference to it internally and use it in the animation callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#container").click(function(){
      var $container = $(this);
      $container.find('img').fadeOut(function() { $container.remove();});
   });
});
```

Comment: If the OP want to remove the whole `<div>` you have to use a local variable, as the `$(this)` will point to the image.

Comment: True, but then he wouldn't have to find the image either, he could just fade out the DIV.

Answer (score 1):

Use $("img",this) where img is whatever child selector of this you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#container").click(function(){
       $("img",this).fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove();});
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

by using this as a second param in your "search"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#container").click(function(){
    $('img',this).fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove();});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$("img", this).fadeOut(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .find() on $(this)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#container").click(function(){
    $(this).find("img").fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove();});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second parameter to specify a context (the element to query inside).

Instead of:

```
$(this:image)
```

Use:

```
$('img', $(this))
```

That will select all `img` tags within your `div`.

Comment: I don't think you should wrap this in $(...). Context should be an element not another jquery object.

Comment: The context can be jQuery, but can also be a DOM element.  According to the docs `$(selector,context)` is equivalent to `$(context).find('selector')` so it would translate into `$($(this)).find('img')` which is legal if redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#container").click(function(){
    $(this).children('image').fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove();});
 });
```